# How to understand $P^B_{B'}$ an orthogonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonal-matrices

How to show that if two basis B, B' are orthonormal basis of V, then the change of coordinate matrix $P^B_{B'}$ is an orthogonal matrix.
I can understand it in the way that we rewrite $P^B_{B'}=\left(P^{B'}_\varepsilon\right)^{-1}P^B_\varepsilon$, but how to just directly understand it by $P^B_{B'}$ itself has orthonormal columns?

Comment: It suffices to note that for column-vectors $x$ and $y$, we have $[P^B_{B'}x]^T[P^B_{B'}y] = x^Ty$.